# Eclipse lock execution so it cannot be terminated accidentally

Tags: eclipse

I am running multiple executions in my Eclipse. One is supposed to run for weeks and just crunch data. But at the same time I develop and regularly kill processes during i.e. debugging. It often happens that I accidentally kill the wrong task and days of calculations are gone. I do not really want to duplicate/split workspaces. Ideally I want to lock the long term task, so I have to unlock/confirm before it can be terminated. I googled but did not get any helpful results.

Eclipse Version:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Comment: I don't think that you can lock it but you can definitely use preShutdown hooks through which you can get a custom confirm message.

Comment: Eclipse is not really intended for running such long running code. You develop and test the code in Eclipse, but the 'production' run is done outside Eclipse (from the command line for example).

Comment: Thats actually really true and super easy.. thanks greg, bad habits grow fast ;)

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Workspace_ you might set the window title to `DO NOT KILL ME!11` as a hint for yourself.